# Some websites not loading on Arch Linux

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dns, routing

So yesterday I installed Arch Linux with KDE on an old computer and also in a virtual machine (VirtualBox). Both installations seem to work fine and I can use them regularly.

But there was one issue (on both installations): Many websites won't load. 
I can't even ping them. Websites like YouTube, Google, etc., work fine. 
But other ones like Reddit, Twitter, and GitHub are just unable to load. 
Because of that I also can't install specific packages and apps.

Details: So the browser replies with "unable to connect". Curl responds with a "curl: (7) Failed to connect to [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) port 80 after 5028 ms: Network is unreachable" and also ping replies with "Destination Net Unreachable". It basically doesn't connect at all. I also tried changing DNS-Server twice, but it did not work. Dig and nslookup do throw out standard outputs. My network seems to be fine. Also every other device (Windows, Android, etc.) (but not an Arch installation) seem to work in this network.

Referring to my local machine, I am not aware of installing anything that could potentially block websites or similar. 
Also I did not touch my local firewall settings.

What should I do to diagnose and fix the issue?

Comment: You seem to have a dns resolution issue even though you report being selectively able to connect to 'some' pages. It would be helpful to show us some outputs for web pages rhat do not seem to load.

Comment: When you try to ping one of the sites that you can’t reach, does it tell you what IP address it’s using? Are you saying that ``dig`` and ``nslookup`` give you correct IP addresses for sites you can’t reach? (Maybe show us an *example* of that output, too.) If you ping an IP address like 140.82.113.3 (github.com) or 104.244.42.193 (twitter.com), what happens? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Two obvious possibilities:

- **DNS** issues, `dig` can show how the requested websites are resolved
- **routing** issues: have a look at your routing table (`ip route`) and do the same for IPv6 if enabled on your system. You can also run: `ip route get` followed by an IP address to find out the determined route path eg: `ip route get 8.8.8.8`.

It would not surprise me that is is an **IPv6 issue**. You may have the IPv6 stack enabled but no suitable route. The browser may be resolving some hosts to IPv6 addresses in priority, that would explain that some succeed while others do not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have at least one public nameserver in your `resolv.conf`, i.e. `google 8.8.8.8`

Make sure you have a default route configured, which can be done from the command line as root:

```bash
/usr/sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

Where `192.168.0.1` is replaced by your router IP address...

This is what worked for me, I had the same problem.  I could connect to some things but not others, and it seemed related to ipv4 vs ipv6.

**Note:** This won't be persistent on reboot unless it's included in your network configuration file.  On `systemd-networkd.service` add the lines:

```
[Route]

Gateway=192.168.0.1
```

And now it will be functional after reboot.

Good Luck!

Comment: This would be a reasonable answer if the OP couldn’t connect to ***any*** site.  How do you explain the fact that some sites work and others don’t?  How does ipv4 vs ipv6 factor into it?

Comment: I don't think I can or need to explain how IPV4 and IPV6 are different beyond that they ARE different.  I'm not working in the stacks hacking the code underneath and I don't claim to be an expert.  But it seems IPV6 works out of the box and IPV4 has to be configured.  I hope the OP will try this, because this is how network support has been configured on linux for decades.